# Is it possible compare staged and stashed versions of files in git?

Tags: git, git-diff

Some times ago I stashed files. Now I stage some.

Is there a way to compare those versions of files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
git diff --cached stash@{n} -- file
```

where `n` corresponds to the stash number of the stash you wish to diff against.

Comment: You should probably mention that `n` should be replaced by the number of the desired stash, based on the output of `git stash list`.

Comment: Yeah, let me add that

Comment: Note also that `stash` or `stash@{1}` etc always points to the `w` commit in the two or three commits that `git stash` made. If you wish to compare to the `i` (index) commit, use `stash^2` or `stash@{n}^2`.